# Does py linter execute file for checking?

Tags: python, pylint

Does py linter execute the code for checking it for errors, etc? I surfed the internet and found no information about it.

Comment: Put a new python file in an empty directory. Do not execute the python file. Run the lint process. If you see a new .pyc file created after linting (you may need to allow showing hidden files), then it probably does execute the file. If not, it probably doesn't.

Comment: @JacobIRR Hidden files are showing now. `.pyc` file does not creates when linting, but it is not creating even when I run `python somefile.py` so I cannot check it this way, probably

Comment: in that case, add a line in the python file that makes a file, writes to a log, etc. so that you can have an external source of testing when the file gets executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

pylint is a static code analysis tool. This means that the analysis is performed without executing the code.